# Make sure a job is rerun in later pipelines if it has failed in previous pipeline and is subject to files changes rules in Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a Gitlab CI job that has a rule making the job run if any of 3 paths are modified. I made the job fail purposefully. Then, I modified the `README.md` - a file that is not tracked by the job `changes` rule - and I pushed a new commit.

But the job was not retried. It therefore does not show the pipeline as failing, while the failing job has never been fixed (it just has not been rerun).

[image: The job has not been rerun]

What kind of rules can I set such that:

- a job has a `rules` `changes` affected by some files
  AND
- a job is retried at every pipeline in the branch/MR if it has not been resolved (regardless of `changes` status).

The pipeline:

```yaml
image: python:3.6-alpine

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: never
    - when: always

stages:
  - lint

flake8:
  image: python:3.6-alpine
  stage: lint
  before_script:
  - pip3 install flake8
  script:
    - echo "Running flake8.."
    - flake8 setup.py src
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: always
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      changes:
        - setup.py
        - src/**/*
        - .gitlab-ci.yml
  tags:
    - sometag
```

I have the following file architecture:

```
.
├── .gitlab-ci.yml
├── README.md
├── setup.py
└── src
    ├── foo.py
    └── __init__.py
```

Comment: Had the exact same question come up today. I have rules that say don't run certain jobs if certain related files are not changed BUT if the pipeline fails before those jobs got to run, and I don't change a file in that specific rule that didn't get a chance to run, then the next run only runs the files I changed. Which means, out of two runs, not all jobs are tested.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and even though I'm not completely satisfied with this solution, I ended up using [`rules:changes:compare_to`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschangescompare_to).
So the job will run every time if a MR contains those changes, even though current commit doesn't include these changes.
But the downside is it will run even if it didn't fail in previous pipelines.

```
rules:
- if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  changes:
    - src/**/*
  compare_to: main
```

Note that `compare_to` doesn't support variable expansion yet ([See this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/369916)). So something like `compare_to: $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH` won't work.